# unlink is showing error that is not present

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to delete image from server but `unlink` is showing error that is not a error at all. My code is given below:

```
private function delete_image($ad_id){
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $sql = "SELECT image1,image2,image3 from ads where AdId = ?";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($ad_id));
    //for fetching result 
    $result = $query->result_array();
    //to make a array of all images
    $img = [$result[0]['image1'],$result[0]['image2'],$result[0]['image3']];
    $i = 0;
    while ($img[$i]!= "edubuylogo.png" && $i<3){
        unlink('./uploads/'.$img[$i]);
        $i++;  
    }   
}
```

and the link to image is http://localhost/edubuy/uploads/IMG_20180120_210433.jpg

And image is perfectly loading.
The error is Message:

> unlink(/uploads/IMG_20180120_210433.jpg): No such file or directory

Comment: your image link is on "your" machine, we can't see it. Drag and drop an image to edit it.

Comment: But I am stating the problem. The image on my machine is well accessible

Comment: right; your computer because you used `http://localhost...` and the hyperlink here leads to http://localhost/edubuy/uploads/IMG_20180120_210433.jpg as if it's trying to access my own machine or others, that's why it's showing up on "your" pc and not here on Stack.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your computer is confused, and you should specify an absolute path. In CodeIgniter you can use the FCPATH constant, so do like this:

```
unlink( FCPATH . 'uploads/' . $img[$i] );
```

That assumes your index.php file is inside edubuy. If it's not then:

```
unlink( FCPATH . 'edubuy/uploads/' . $img[$i] );
```

Comment: maybe the image doesn't exist

Comment: Do me a favor and update your question with the absolute path to your image. Also, let us know what the absolute path to your website's front controller (index.php) is.